# Destination Path Too Long - Windows 10 w/ Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

I have a Windows 10 machine updated with the Anniversary update. When I try to copy a file from an external USB hard drive using windows explorer, I get the following Error :

Destination Path Too Long

The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder.  You can shorten the file name and try again, or try a location that has a shorter path.

I found an article to enable long file names using the local group policy editor :

http://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

However, this doesn't work for me.  I do not see the option to enable.  SO, I manually edit the registry setting by adding the key and value.  Even after several reboots, this didn't allow the file to be copied.

The computer is part of a domain so I searched for the flag in the domain group policy editor but it is not listed.  The domain server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Is there anything else I can do to get the file copied (in reality there are thousands of files I am trying to copy from an external hard drive to a Windows Surface Book).

Comment: Are you using explorer to make the copy or something else? Article mentions `There is one caveat. This new setting won’t necessarily work with every application out there, but it will work with most.`

Comment: Yes I read that as well.  I am using windows explorer to copy the files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The application [must have an entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/) in its [manifest file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711.aspx) to enable it:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
      <longPathAware>true</longPathAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

otherwise the `MAX_PATH` issue still occurs. I've asked a Microsoft employee why Windows Explorer still has the issue and I got the answer, that Explorer is not ready to use it. Microsoft still works to get Explorer compatible to long file names/paths.

Comment: I am using windows explorer to copy.  Where do I find the manifest file for it?

Comment: @JustAspMe I asked Microsoft and got an answer. See the edit.